# Mule ESB and MQTT Connector: subscribe multiple topics

Tags: mule, mqtt

using Mule and MQTT I can't subscribe a client to multiple topics.

I configure config global element in this way:

```
<mqtt:config name="mqttSubscriber" doc:name="MQTT" brokerServerUri="${mqtt.url}" clientId="#['spy@'+server.host]" password="${mqtt.username}" username="${mqtt.password}">
   <mqtt:connection-pooling-profile initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_WAIT" maxActive="1" maxIdle="1" maxWait="1"/>
</mqtt:config>
```

In a flow I use:

```
<mqtt:subscribe config-ref="mqttSubscriber" doc:name="MQTTSubscriber1" topicFilter="a" qos="ONLY_ONCE"/>
```

and in another flow:

```
<mqtt:subscribe config-ref="mqttSubscriber" doc:name="MQTTSubscriber2" topicFilter="b" qos="ONLY_ONCE"/>
```

When the application starts, it is subscribed only to one topic.

What is wrong on my configuration? Maybe I have to create different clients?

Thanks at all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, only one `mqtt:subscribe` is allowed per `mqtt:config` so you need to either:

- Create a second `mqtt:config` and use it in the second `mqtt:subscribe`
- Create a [single multi-filter subscription](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-mqtt/blob/master/src/test/resources/mqtt-connector-tests-config.xml#L31-L35) and use a `choice` message processor to route messages based on the value of the `mqtt.topicName` inbound message property.

The latter would be better IMO since you'll only have a single active connection and it leverages MQTT's capacity to subscribe to multiple topics at once.